# What would happen in the variant of the Josephus problem in which people in odd-numbered positions are killed in each round?

Tags: algorithms

What would happen in the variant of the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) in which people in odd-numbered positions are killed in each round?

For example, with $N=10$ people:
$$
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \to 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 \to 4 ,8 \to 8.
$$

As you can see in the above example the killing starts from position $1$.

I was just curious to find out what would be the solution to this variant. I tried out different values of $n$ but could not find a proper algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position $2^{\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor}$ is always safe since it is the position that maximizes the number of trailing zeros in its binary representation.

Claim: The person originally sitting in position $n$ is killed in the $i$-th round iff the binary representation of $n$ has exactly $i-1$ trailing zeroes.

Proof: By strong induction on $i$. If $i=1$ the claim is trivially true since $n$ has $0$ trailing zeroes iff $n$ is odd.
If $i > 1$, by induction hypothesis we have that all remaining people were originally sitting in positions whose binary representation has $i$ or more trailing zeros, i.e, those positions are exactly the integers in $S = \{1, \dots, N\}$ that are multiples of $2^i$.
If $n=2^i k$ then there are exactly $k$ positions in $S$ smaller than or equal to $n$, i.e., $n$ is killed iff $k$ is odd.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand how you reached out to 2^(log2N)

Comment: $2^{\lfloor\log_2 N\rfloor}$ is the sole largest power of $2$ not larger than $N$, i.e., it is the unique position in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ with the property that its binary representation has the largest number of trailing zeros. From the claim in my answer, it follows that all people initially sitting in some other position will be killed before the one sitting in the $2^{\rfloor\log_2 N\rfloor}$-th position. You can see this in your example: the surviving positions are multiples of $2^0$, then of $2^1$, then of $2^2$, and finally the only multiple of $2^3=2^{\lfloor\log_2 10\rfloor}$ remains.

Comment: Ohh right got it, thank you!